# Access OData in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am getting an error as the below

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sap host

I tried to connect using request module and used the method GET. I used base64 encoded authorization parameter were also passed to the options but still getting the same error.

Comment: Ciao, can you show some code in order to better undestand your problem?

Comment: var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
 
var client = new Client();
var url = url_ct
var args = {            
  headers: {
             //   //You need to BASE64 encode your user and password
               'Authorization': 'Basic a3duYzY2NTpNb2hhbkBzbTY=',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
};
var data = client.get(url,args, function(data){
    if (data != undefined) {
        console.log("Connection established");
    }
});

Comment: url_ct is the odata url from my system but i get the below errow
"errorMessage":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND "my system host"

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, interesting error. According to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) you are correctly using `client.get` request. I found [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5436) discussion. They talking about `hhtp.get` so it's not exaclty your problem BUT I think the error is the same.
In brief:

This is the first suggestion:

> getaddrinfo is by definition a DNS issue. Does dig host or nslookup host work? Does dns.lookup(host, console.log) work?

The second one is:

> Setting the family to 4 is working.

```
var options = {
  host: '_host_',
  family: 4,
  port: 80,
  path: '/'
};
```

Try to put `family: 4` in your args. This could solve your problem.